# How to plot the movement of points as I change the slider

Tags: manipulate

I have this code that generates an Edgeworth both with two optimum points. The optimal points change as I move the slider. I would like to plot/trace the change in the optimal so that at the end I can see in a graph how the optimum moved with the change in slider's value. Anyone can help please? Here is my code:

```
sigma = 1.5;
a11 = 0.4;
a21 = 0.6;
a12 = 0.4;
a22 = 0.6;
t12 = 1;
t21 = 1;
u1 = Function[{xa1, 
    xa2}, (a11^(1/sigma)*xa1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a21^(1/sigma)*xa2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
u2 = Function[{xb1, 
    xb2}, (a12^(1/sigma)*xb1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a22^(1/sigma)*xb2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
SetOptions[ContourPlot, 
 ContourShading -> None]; SetOptions[RegionPlot, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Mesh -> Full, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]];
ICmap = Show[
   ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Red, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   ContourPlot[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Blue, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   Graphics[{Dashed, Opacity[.2], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]];
InvTicks = Table[{.2 (i - 1), 1 - .2 (i - 1)}, {i, 6}];

Manipulate[
 uMax = {ArgMax[{u1[xa1, xa2], 
     And[xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 == e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], 
      0 <= xa1 <= 1, 0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}], 
   ArgMax[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2], 
     And[t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) == 
       1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), 0 <= xa1 <= 1, 
      0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}]};

 BudgetSets1 = {RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 <= e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2,
      0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Red]], 
   RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 > e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 
     0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Blue]]};

 BudgetSets2 = {RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) <= 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Green]], 
   RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) > 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Yellow]]};

 tangentICs = 
  ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2] == u1 @@ uMax[[1]], 
    u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2] == u2 @@ (1 - uMax[[2]])}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2,
     0, 1}, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[.01], 
      Opacity[.7]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.01], Opacity[.6]]}];

 optPoints = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], {Red, (Point[uMax[[1]]])}, {Blue, (Point[
       uMax[[2]]])}}];
Show @@ {BudgetSets1, BudgetSets2, tangentICs, optPoints, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, InvTicks}, {Automatic, 
      InvTicks}}, \[CapitalDelta] = uMax[[2, 1]] - uMax[[1, 1]]; 
   FrameLabel -> 
    Which[\[CapitalDelta] < 
      0, {{None, "excess supply of y"}, {"excess demand for x", 
       None}}, \[CapitalDelta] > 
      0, {{None, "excess demand for y"}, {"excess supply of x", 
       None}}, \[CapitalDelta] == 
      0, {{None, "market clears"}, {"market clears", 
       None}}]}, {{\[Rho], 1}, 1/2, 2}, {{e, {3/4, 1/4}}, Locator}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False, ControlType -> VerticalSlider, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick implementation; not terribly elegant but gets the job done.  I've added two checkboxes which allow the user to add a point to a trace line and then clear that line if desired.  The revised code:

```
sigma = 1.5;
a11 = 0.4;
a21 = 0.6;
a12 = 0.4;
a22 = 0.6;
t12 = 1;
t21 = 1;
u1 = Function[{xa1, 
    xa2}, (a11^(1/sigma)*xa1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a21^(1/sigma)*xa2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
u2 = Function[{xb1, 
    xb2}, (a12^(1/sigma)*xb1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a22^(1/sigma)*xb2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
SetOptions[ContourPlot, 
 ContourShading -> None]; SetOptions[RegionPlot, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Mesh -> Full, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]];
ICmap = Show[
   ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Red, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   ContourPlot[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Blue, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   Graphics[{Dashed, Opacity[.2], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]];
InvTicks = Table[{.2 (i - 1), 1 - .2 (i - 1)}, {i, 6}];

Manipulate[
 If[cleartrace == True, (cleartrace = False; trace = {};)];
 uMax = {ArgMax[{u1[xa1, xa2], 
     And[xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 == e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], 
      0 <= xa1 <= 1, 0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}], 
   ArgMax[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2], 
     And[t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) == 
       1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), 0 <= xa1 <= 1, 
      0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}]};
 (* Added here *)
 If[addpt == True, (addpt = False; AppendTo[trace, uMax[[1]]])];
 (* End add *)
 BudgetSets1 = {RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 <= e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2,
      0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Red]], 
   RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 > e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 
     0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Blue]]};
 BudgetSets2 = {RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) <= 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Green]], 
   RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) > 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Yellow]]};
 tangentICs = 
  ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2] == u1 @@ uMax[[1]], 
    u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2] == u2 @@ (1 - uMax[[2]])}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2,
     0, 1}, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[.01], 
      Opacity[.7]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.01], Opacity[.6]]}];
 optPoints = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], {Red, (Point[uMax[[1]]])}, {Blue, (Point[
       uMax[[2]]])},(* Added here *) {Black, Dashed, Line@trace}}];
 Show @@ {BudgetSets1, BudgetSets2, tangentICs, optPoints, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, InvTicks}, {Automatic, 
      InvTicks}}, \[CapitalDelta] = uMax[[2, 1]] - uMax[[1, 1]];
   FrameLabel -> 
    Which[\[CapitalDelta] < 
      0, {{None, "excess supply of y"}, {"excess demand for x", 
       None}}, \[CapitalDelta] > 
      0, {{None, "excess demand for y"}, {"excess supply of x", 
       None}}, \[CapitalDelta] == 
      0, {{None, "market clears"}, {"market clears", 
       None}}]}, {{\[Rho], 1}, 1/2, 2}, {{e, {3/4, 1/4}}, 
  Locator}, {addpt, {True, False}, 
  ControlType -> Checkbox}, {{cleartrace, False}, {True, False}, 
  ControlType -> Checkbox}, ContinuousAction -> False, 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Left,
 (* Added here *) Initialization :> (trace = {};)]
```

...and sample output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's my go. I use global variables, which is not quite the best way, but it works. If you change `e` then I erase the memory. I also took the liberty of taking all your definitions outside of the `Manipulate` block, because I find it more elegant.

```
sigma = 1.5;
a11 = 0.4;
a21 = 0.6;
a12 = 0.4;
a22 = 0.6;
t12 = 1;
t21 = 1;
u1 = Function[{xa1, 
    xa2}, (a11^(1/sigma)*xa1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a21^(1/sigma)*xa2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
u2 = Function[{xb1, 
    xb2}, (a12^(1/sigma)*xb1^((sigma - 1)/sigma) + 
      a22^(1/sigma)*xb2^((sigma - 1)/sigma))^(sigma/(sigma - 1))];
SetOptions[ContourPlot, 
 ContourShading -> None]; SetOptions[RegionPlot, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Mesh -> Full, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]];
ICmap = Show[
   ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Red, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   ContourPlot[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2]}, {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Table[Directive[Blue, Opacity[i/10]], {i, 10}]], 
   Graphics[{Dashed, Opacity[.2], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]];
InvTicks = Table[{.2 (i - 1), 1 - .2 (i - 1)}, {i, 6}];
\[Rho]List = {};
uList = {};
globale = {3/4, 1/4};
uMax[e_, \[Rho]_] := uMax[e, \[Rho]] = Module[{result},
    If[Thread[e != globale], \[Rho]List = {}; uList = {}; globale = e];
    result = {ArgMax[{u1[xa1, xa2], 
        And[xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 == e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], 
         0 <= xa1 <= 1, 0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}], 
      ArgMax[{u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2], 
        And[t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) == 
          1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), 0 <= xa1 <= 1, 
         0 <= xa2 <= 1]}, {xa1, xa2}]};
    AppendTo[\[Rho]List, \[Rho]];
    AppendTo[uList, result];
    result
    ];
BudgetSets1[
   e_, \[Rho]_] := {RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 <= e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2,
      0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Red]], 
   RegionPlot[
    xa1 + \[Rho]*t21*xa2 > e[[1]] + \[Rho]*e[[2]], {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 
     0, 1}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Blue]]};
BudgetSets2[
   e_, \[Rho]_] := {RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) <= 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.07], Green]], 
   RegionPlot[
    t12 (1 - xa1) + \[Rho]*t12*(1 - xa2) > 
     1 - e[[1]] + \[Rho]*(1 - e[[2]]), {xa1, 0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.05], Yellow]]};
tangentICs[e_, \[Rho]_] := 
  ContourPlot[{u1[xa1, xa2] == u1 @@ uMax[e, \[Rho]][[1]], 
    u2[1 - xa1, 1 - xa2] == u2 @@ (1 - uMax[e, \[Rho]][[2]])}, {xa1, 
    0, 1}, {xa2, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[.01], Opacity[.7]], 
     Directive[Blue, Thickness[.01], Opacity[.6]]}];
optPoints[e_, \[Rho]_] := 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], {Red, (Point[
       uMax[e, \[Rho]][[1]]])}, {Blue, (Point[
       uMax[e, \[Rho]][[2]]])}}];
label[e_, \[Rho]_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = 
    uMax[e, \[Rho]][[2, 1]] - uMax[e, \[Rho]][[1, 1]]},
  Which[\[CapitalDelta] < 
    0, {{None, "excess supply of y"}, {"excess demand for x", 
     None}}, \[CapitalDelta] > 
    0, {{None, "excess demand for y"}, {"excess supply of x", 
     None}}, \[CapitalDelta] == 
    0, {{None, "market clears"}, {"market clears", None}}]
  ]
line := Module[{perm},
  If[Length[\[Rho]List] == 0, Graphics[],
   perm = Ordering[\[Rho]List];
   Graphics[{Red, Line[uList[[perm, 1]]], Blue, 
     Line[uList[[perm, 2]]]}]
   ]
  ]
Manipulate[
 Show[BudgetSets1[e, \[Rho]], BudgetSets2[e, \[Rho]], 
  tangentICs[e, \[Rho]], optPoints[e, \[Rho]], line, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, InvTicks}, {Automatic, InvTicks}},
  FrameLabel -> label[e, \[Rho]]],
 {{\[Rho], 1}, 1/2, 2}, {{e, {3/4, 1/4}}, Locator}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False, ControlType -> VerticalSlider, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Result:

[image]